# Как исправить адаптивное меню

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, меню

После адаптирования под телефон, не открывается меню по вертикали.
Что я упустил? Или чего не добавил? Подскажите пожалуйста!

```
  <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylessheet" media="only screen and (max-width:700px)" href="style.css"/>

<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var delay_popup = 5000;
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
</script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var touch = $('#touch-menu');
            var menu = $('.menu');

            $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });
            $(window).resize(function(){
                var wid = $(window).width();
                if(wid > 760 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                    menu.removeAttr('style');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<a href="#" id="touch-menu">Меню</a>
<div class="alone">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="menu">
<ul align="center">
<li style="float:left; margin-left:10%;"><a href="">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
<li style="float:left; margin-left:5%;"><a href="" style="clear:both;">ГАЛЕРЕЯ</a></li>
<img src="" align="center" class="logo"/>
<li style="float:right;  margin-right:10%;"><a href="">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
<li style="float:right; margin-right:5%; "><a href="">О НАС</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="right"></div></div>
</header>
<div id="container">
</div>


</body>
</html>

    *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div{
    display:block;
}
body{
   background: url(images/.jpg);
  background-color:#fff;
}
header {
    height:7%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.right{
float:left;
    background-color: #000;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
    }
.menu{float:left;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
width:70%;
height:100%;
 }
.left{float:left;
    background-color: #000;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;

}
img{
    border:none;
}

.menu ul {
    margin-left:10%;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#cee2d3;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#touch-menu{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#cee2d3;
    list-style-type: none;
}


.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width:10%;
    background-color:#669900; text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.menu ul li a, #touch-menu { 
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

.menu li a:hover, #touch-menu:hover { color:#f2f2f2;}
 #touch-menu{display:none;}
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .alone {display: none;}
    .menu ul  li {float: none;}
    .menu ul li a {
        border-top: 1px solid #eee;
        background: #fff;
        color: #666;
    }
    .menu ul li:first-child a {border-top: none;}
    .menu ul li a:hover {
        background: #f0f0f0;
        color: #444;
        border-left: 3px solid #515572;
    }
    #touch-menu {display: block;}
}
```

Comment: из своего опыта скажу, что надпись menu.is(':hidden') не очень правильная. по пробуй menu.is(':hidden') == true явно написать

Comment: Исправил этот пункт, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: вынеси это  menu.is(':hidden') в функию внутрь если if(wid<760){ menu.is(':hidden')} else { menu.removeAttr('style');}

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд код очень плохой. Но ошибка в нем кроется здесь

```js
 $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });
```

и тут

```html
<div class="alone">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul align="center">
                    <li style="float:left; margin-left:10%;"><a href="">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
                    <li style="float:left; margin-left:5%;"><a href="" style="clear:both;">ГАЛЕРЕЯ</a></li>
                    <img src="" align="center" class="logo" />
                    <li style="float:right;  margin-right:10%;"><a href="">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
                    <li style="float:right; margin-right:5%; "><a href="">О НАС</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
```

у тебя в ccs указано, что если ширина экрана меньше 768, то класс alone скрывается

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .alone {display: none;}
```

значит и само меню тоже становиться скрытым и не важно что ты будешь делать с ним, пока вышестоящий тег не будет виден меню не появится

Перепиши обработчик $(touch) вот так

```js
$(touch).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (menu.is(':hidden') == true) {
                    $('.alone').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('.alone').hide();
                }
                menu.slideToggle();
            });
```

Но это не решение проблемы, я лишь показываю место ошибки

Comment: Попробовал, все равно никакого результата при нажатии